# Installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, stringr

Please help me to install stringr package in R. The result is:

```
install.packages("stringi")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kozlovpy/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
пробую URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-08-27/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_0.5-5.zip'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  не могу открыть URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-08-27/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_0.5-5.zip'
Вдобавок: Предупреждение:
В download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  'InternetOpenUrl' не удалось: 'Операция прервана по таймауту'
Предупреждение в download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  скачивание пакета ‘stringi’ не удалось

sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.2   tools_3.2.2  gtable_0.1.2 Rcpp_0.11.5  grid_3.2.2   digest_0.6.8 proto_0.3-10
```

Thanks for link, zx8754. I tried to follow recomendations in your link, and result is the next (not positive):

1. Name is OK
2. Just set all possible repositories
3. Package is of course in repositories
4. 'stringr' is of course a package
5. My R is not out of date, I recently upgrated it to 3.2.0 version
6. 'stringr' is not an archive package
7. This did not give positive result:

   > install.packages("stringr", type = "source") 
   >  
   >   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kozlovpy/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’ 
   >  
   >   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
   >  
   >   also installing the dependency ‘stringi’

   пробую URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-08-27/src/contrib/stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz' 
    
   Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3639183 bytes (3.5 MB) 
    
   downloaded 3.5 MB

   пробую URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-08-27/src/contrib/stringr_1.0.0.tar.gz' 
    
   Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 34880 bytes (34 KB) 
    
   downloaded 34 KB

   - installing *source* package 'stringi' ... 
      
     ** пакет 'stringi' удачно распакован, MD5 sums проверены 
      
     Предупреждение: работающая команда 'sh ./configure.win' имеет статус 127 
      
     ERROR: configuration failed for package 'stringi'
   - removing 'C:/Users/kozlovpy/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringi' 
      
     ERROR: dependency 'stringi' is not available for package 'stringr'
   - removing 'C:/Users/kozlovpy/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/stringr'

   Скачанные исходники пакетов находятся в 
    
           ‘C:\Users\kozlovpy\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgnfwL4\downloaded_packages’ 
   Предупреждения: 
   1: работающая команда '"C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" 
    
   CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\kozlovpy\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" 
    
   C:\Users\kozlovpy\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgnfwL4/downloaded_packages/stringi_0.5-5.tar.gz' имеет статус 1 
   2: В install.packages("stringr", type = "source") : 
     установка пакета ‘stringi’ имеет ненулевой статус выхода 
   3: работающая команда '"C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" 
   CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\kozlovpy\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" 
    
   C:\Users\kozlovpy\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgnfwL4/downloaded_pac 
    
   kages/stringr_1.0.0.tar.gz' имеет статус 1 
   4: В install.packages("stringr", type = "source") : 
     установка пакета ‘stringr’ имеет ненулевой статус выхода
8. Github packages shows the next:

   > install_github("hadley/stringr") 
   >   Downloading github repo hadley/stringr@master 
   >   Ошибка в loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
   >     there is no package called ‘stringi’ 
   >   install_github("Rexamine/stringi") 
   >   Downloading github repo Rexamine/stringi@master 
   >   Ошибка в loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
   >     there is no package called ‘stringi’
9. options(install.packages.check.source = "no") didn't help too
10. Trying to enter different repos - no hopes.

Any guesses what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884)